# Eager Loading Include a List of element in a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I am trying to use eager loading by specifying a list of elements that need to be included.This is the expresion I have written:

```
public class Prefetch<TEntity>
{
    private readonly List<LambdaExpression> items = new List<LambdaExpression>();

    public Prefetch<TEntity> Include<TPath>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TPath>> path)
    {
        this.items.Add(path);

            return this;
        }
}

 private static IEnumerable<string> GetCoverPrefetch()
    {

         new Prefetch<ContractCoverInstance>().Include(x => x.Tariff.AksAssumptionData.ToList().ForEach(x => x.MortalityTableMainInsuredMale))
    }
```

I am not sure if what I have written is correct and will do what I am expecting and I can not test the application for some time because there are a long series of compile errors ,because of some model changes, that need to be corrected before the application is tested.

This is what I believe this expression will do please correct me If I am wrong:

> For Each elements in the List resulted in AksAssumptionData get the
>   MortalityTableMainInsuredMale and Include it

If this is not correct then how can I achieve what I just sayd in a lambda expression?

Comment: I would suggest you correct the other errors with your code, test this query, and _then_ come back if you have a problem.

Comment: This is more of a sintax question then an actual problem in the application , and there are parts of the system that I can not touch and have to w8 for others

Comment: Why not test the code externally? It wouldn't be hard to copy the classes and provide some dummy data to work with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `items` should be a list of `TEntity` ... why would you have a list of lambda expressions?
2. You are using Include as if it's a singleton ... not a good design, in my opinion.
3. `GetCoverPrefetch` is supposed to return an `IEnumerable<string>`, according to the signature, but what do you expect the string to contain?  You aren't returning a string from the function.  You are just using `ForEach` to do nothing - it will give you a compile error.  You should use an ordinary `foreach` and use `yield return`, or just `return new Prefetch<ContractCoverInstance>().Include(...)` but what Include is returning is not an `IEnumerable<string>`, it's a `List<LambdaExpression>`.
4. It doesn't make any sense.  Even if you returned `items` from `GetCoverPrefetch()` properly
   it would just contain the lambda expression you passed in.  So it does nothing.